# Bot is not changing user's nicknames when he/she joins the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to change the user's nickname when he or she joins the server
Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.edit(nick=f"[{CLAN_TAG}]{member.nick}")
```

The bot is not changing the user's nick when someone is joining the server

Comment: Any error or is it just silently not working?

Comment: do you have member intents enabled

Comment: Yes I turned on intent

Comment: Not only the intent, also in the Discord Dev Portal

Comment: It is silently not working :[

Comment: Yes I did on dev portal

Comment: Also for your bot/in your code?

Comment: And has your bots the manage nicknames permissions?

Comment: Yes it has permission

Comment: Maybe you want to show more proof in the question, i.e. more code and a screenshot of the bot permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user dosnt have nickname then **member.nick** is **none**. 
You use **on_member_join** then when user join to server he dont have nickname.
If you use **member.name** you will get member current name and 
her nickname will be "**[CLAN_TAG]Seekii**" (example)

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.edit(nick=f"[{CLAN_TAG}]{member.name}")
```